# plink: unknown option "--file"/"--freq"/"--out"

Tags: plink

I am a new for Plink. I run Plink 1.9 on my mac by following the website tutorial. Why these basic options are unknown?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Tz1e.png)

There are codes:

```
gongjingwen@gongjingwendeMacBook-Pro ~ % cd ~ /Users/gongjingwen/plink_mac 
~/plink_mac
gongjingwen@gongjingwendeMacBook-Pro plink_mac % ./plink
PLINK v1.90p 64-bit (30 Nov 2019)              www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/
(C) 2005-2019 Shaun Purcell, Christopher Chang   GNU General Public License v3

  plink <input flag(s)...> [command flag(s)...] [other flag(s)...]
  plink --help [flag name(s)...]

Commands include --make-bed, --recode, --flip-scan, --merge-list,
--write-snplist, --list-duplicate-vars, --freqx, --missing, --test-mishap,
--hardy, --mendel, --ibc, --impute-sex, --indep-pairphase, --r2, --show-tags,
--blocks, --distance, --genome, --homozyg, --make-rel, --make-grm-gz,
--rel-cutoff, --cluster, --pca, --neighbour, --ibs-test, --regress-distance,
--model, --bd, --gxe, --logistic, --dosage, --lasso, --test-missing,
--make-perm-pheno, --unrelated-heritability, --tdt, --dfam, --qfam, --tucc,
--annotate, --clump, --gene-report, --meta-analysis, --epistasis,
--fast-epistasis, and --score.

"plink --help | more" describes all functions (warning: long).
gongjingwen@gongjingwendeMacBook-Pro plink_mac % plink --file toy --freq --out toy_analysis
plink: unknown option "--file"
plink: unknown option "--freq"
plink: unknown option "--out"
```

Please tell me how to solve it
QAQ
Thank u!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem here is that there are two different programs called `plink`:

1. The command line connection utility [plink](https://helpmanual.io/help/plink/)
2. The GWAS toolkit [plink](http://zzz.bwh.harvard.edu/plink/index.shtml)

By calling `plink` you are executing the first one, to run the second one, you need to call `./plink` (note the dot and the slash).

So, in your case, the following command should work:

```
./plink --file toy --freq --out toy_analysis
```